# Why the time format in MySQL is like that? (Marked in red on the applied screenshot)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, time

[image]The `TIME` data type format in `MySQL` is this: `Values range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'.` I don't understand the `-838` part. Why is it `838` and why do we have the `-` sign here? Also, I don't see the part for fractional seconds in `'HH:MM:SS'`. I would appreciate it if somebody could explain it to me.

Comment: The first paragraph here might help https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's `TIME` interval is more of an interval datatype than an actual "time of the day". It allows negative times, and values greater than 24 hours.

`'-838:59:59'` is just that: a negative time with 838 hours, 59 minutes and 59 seconds.

Fractional seconds are supported in times, up to to microseconds (6 digits), as [explained in  the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html):

> MySQL recognizes TIME values in several formats, some of which can include a trailing fractional seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. [...] With the fractional part included, the range for `TIME` values is `'-838:59:59.000000'` to `'838:59:59.000000'`.

You specify the number of fractional seconds digits when creating the `TIME` column, like `TIME(3)` for milliseconds. See [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html) for more details on this.